# How to make a simple tracking android app using android studio

Tags: android, location, tracking

I'm trying to make a simple location tracking app I tried many methods but nothing is working. I think onLocationChanged is not being called.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("test", "onLocationChanged Called");
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    Log.d("location", "Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
}
```

Comment: Do you request permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` before tracking?

Comment: @ChandanKumar  There are many resources publically available. Pls do a research and come back with good explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I already mentioned that I tried all methods. Are you not able to read the question before publishing comment or downvoting,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my Whole code to run App. Just make new Project and Choose Map Project, Make your project on google console and Add the Key to your Project :

Add Permission to manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Java Code :

```
package com.bluebirds.avinash.uberdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient
                .ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private final int MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private Handler handler;
    private Marker m;
//    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    public final static int SENDING = 1;
    public final static int CONNECTING = 2;
    public final static int ERROR = 3;
    public final static int SENT = 4;
    public final static int SHUTDOWN = 5;

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    private Location previousLocation;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {

                    case SENDING:

                        break;

                }

            }
        };
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);

        m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in " +
                "Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // Show rationale and request permission.
        }


    }


    public void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation, final float st) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = st;
        final long duration = 1555;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

                float rot = t * toRotation + (1 - t) * startRotation;

                marker.setRotation(-rot > 180 ? rot / 2 : rot);
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void animateMarker(final LatLng toPosition, final boolean hideMarke) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(m.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 5000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                m.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarke) {
                        m.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        m.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private double bearingBetweenLocations(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {

        double PI = 3.14159;
        double lat1 = latLng1.latitude * PI / 180;
        double long1 = latLng1.longitude * PI / 180;
        double lat2 = latLng2.latitude * PI / 180;
        double long2 = latLng2.longitude * PI / 180;

        double dLon = (long2 - long1);

        double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
                * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

        double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

        brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
        brng = (brng + 360) % 360;

        return brng;
    }


   /* @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]
            grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (permissions.length == 1 &&
                    permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
            }
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    LatLng previouslatLng;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        previouslatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        double rota = 0.0;
        double startrota = 0.0;
        if (previousLocation != null) {

            rota = bearingBetweenLocations(previouslatLng, new LatLng(location.getLatitude
                    (), location.getLongitude()));
        }


        rotateMarker(m, (float) rota, (float) startrota);


        previousLocation = location;
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..........................");
        Log.d(TAG, "lat :" + location.getLatitude() + "long :" + location.getLongitude());
        Log.d(TAG, "bearing :" + location.getBearing());

        animateMarker(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), false);
//        new ServerConnAsync(handler, MapsActivity.this,location).execute();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }
}
```

XML Activity :

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="com.bluebirds.avinash.uberdemo.MapsActivity"/>
```

Comment: on your location service. or download fakelocation app. Turn On your Mock Location. Move your Current location and you will see the marker is moving according to your location.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, you can track start location and end location, the marker moves from start location to end location,

1 .  add Mainfest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="Your string" />
```

2 .  In gradle

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

3 .  Find activty,

```
    public class FindActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    double latitude, logitude,prevLatitude,prevLongitude;
    Button button;
    GPSTracker3 gps;
    String work="0";
    TextView textView, t1, t2, t3;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private List<LatLng> bangaloreRoute;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
    Context mContext;
    Button b1, b2;
    CardView change;
    List<LatLng> list;
    Location location;
    private static final CharSequence[] MAP_TYPE_ITEMS = {"Road Map", "Hybrid", "Satellite", "Terrain"};


    Marker marker;

    private Polyline line;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        mContext = this;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FindActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        } else {
            //  Toast.makeText(mContext,"You need have granted permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gps = new GPSTracker3(mContext, FindActivity.this);

            // Check if GPS enabled
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                logitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + lati + "\nLong: " + longi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Can't get location.
                // GPS or network is not enabled.
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
                //   gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }



        MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
        change = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.locate);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                work = "1";
                b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(latitude, logitude));
//                showMessageLocationUpdate();
            }
        });
        if (bangaloreRoute == null) {
            bangaloreRoute = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            bangaloreRoute.clear();
        }
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // bangaloreRoute.clear();
                list.clear();
                work = "2";
                b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                CaptureMapScreen();
            }
        });
        change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_sate);
        change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                showMapTypeSelectorDialog();

            }
        });

    }

    public void CaptureMapScreen()
    {
        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bitmap = snapshot;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/"
                            + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + ".png");

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        mMap.snapshot(callback);

    }


    private void showMessageLocationUpdate() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        StartCase(location);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 100);
    }

    private void StartCase(Location location) {
        if (work.equals("1")) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            list.add(latLng);
            drawPolyLineOnMap(list);


            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(30));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


       // getAddress(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
       // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

        if (work.equals("1")) {
            list.add(latLng);
            drawPolyLineOnMap(list);
        }
    }



    private void showMapTypeSelectorDialog(){

        final String title = "Select Map Type";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title);

        int checkCurrentMapType = mMap.getMapType() - 1;
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(MAP_TYPE_ITEMS,checkCurrentMapType,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){
                switch(item){
                    case 1:
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                        break;
                    default:
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //build dialog
        AlertDialog fMapTypeDialogue = builder.create();
        fMapTypeDialogue.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        fMapTypeDialogue.show();
    }

    public void drawPolyLineOnMap(List<LatLng> list) {
        PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(Color.RED);
        polyOptions.width(3);
        polyOptions.addAll(list);
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (LatLng latLng : list) {
            builder.include(latLng);
        }
//        final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        //BOUND_PADDING is an int to specify padding of bound.. try 100.
//        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10);
//        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }
    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Address obj = addresses.get(0);
            String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
            String currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                    + obj.getAdminArea();
            double   latitude = obj.getLatitude();
            double longitude = obj.getLongitude();
            String currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
            String currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();



            t1.setText(obj.getAdminArea());
            t2.setText(obj.getSubAdminArea());
            t3.setText(obj.getSubThoroughfare());

            System.out.println("obj.getCountryName()"+obj.getCountryName());
            System.out.println("obj.getCountryCode()"+obj.getCountryCode());
            System.out.println("obj.getAdminArea()"+obj.getAdminArea());
            System.out.println("obj.getPostalCode()"+obj.getPostalCode());
            System.out.println("obj.getSubAdminArea()"+obj.getSubAdminArea());
            System.out.println("obj.getLocality()"+obj.getLocality());
            System.out.println("obj.getSubThoroughfare()"+obj.getSubThoroughfare());


            Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                return;
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/balwinderSingh1989/androidBestLocationTracker
a simple to integrate lib with location algorithms that would get best location from GPS or network (whatever is avaiable)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as reference project :- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: onLocationChanged not called